# Grails JNDI data source not working

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, jndi

I have a grails application with a data source defined in DataSource.groovy as:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName = "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
    username = "myusername"
    password = "mypassword"
}
hibernate {
    cache.use_second_level_cache = true
    cache.use_query_cache = false
    cache.region.factory_class = 'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate.EhCacheRegionFactory'
}
// environment specific settings
environments {
    development {
        dataSource {
            dbCreate = "validate"
            url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:1521:instance"
        logSql = true
        }

    }
}
```

This all works fine but I want to use a JNDI data source.

In Config.groovy I have:

```
grails.naming.entries = [
'jdbc/pms_dev': [
    type: 'java.sql.DataSource',
    auth: 'Container',
    description: 'Main datasource',

    url: 'jdbc:oracle:thin:@server:1521:instance',
    username: "myusername",
    password: "mypassword",
    driverClassName: "oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver",
    maxActive: "8",
    maxIdle: "4"
    ]
]
```

I change DataSource.groovy's development section to:

```
development {
    dataSource {
        dbCreate = "validate"
        jndiName = "java:comp/env/jdbc/pms_dev"
        logSql = true
    }
}
```

Now I get the following error when do grails runApp:

```
| Error 2014-02-06 11:25:58,402 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing the application: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
   Line | Method
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
->> 146 | getObjectInstance in org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   304 | getObjectInstance in javax.naming.spi.NamingManager
|   843 | lookup . in org.apache.naming.NamingContext
|   154 | lookup   in     ''
|   831 | lookup . in     ''
|   154 | lookup   in     ''
|   831 | lookup . in     ''
|   154 | lookup   in     ''
|   831 | lookup . in     ''
|   168 | lookup   in     ''
|   158 | lookup . in org.apache.naming.SelectorContext
|   392 | lookup   in javax.naming.InitialContext
|   303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2014-02-06 11:25:58,574 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoader  - Error initializing Grails: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
   Line | Method
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
->> 146 | getObjectInstance in org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   304 | getObjectInstance in javax.naming.spi.NamingManager
|   843 | lookup . in org.apache.naming.NamingContext
|   154 | lookup   in     ''
|   831 | lookup . in     ''
|   154 | lookup   in     ''
|   831 | lookup . in     ''
|   154 | lookup   in     ''
|   831 | lookup . in     ''
|   168 | lookup   in     ''
|   158 | lookup . in org.apache.naming.SelectorContext
|   392 | lookup   in javax.naming.InitialContext
|   303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2014-02-06 11:25:58,887 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR [localhost].[/osrpms]  - Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
Message: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
   Line | Method
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSourceUnproxied' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceUnproxied': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
->> 303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
Caused by NamingException: Cannot create resource instance
->> 146 | getObjectInstance in org.apache.naming.factory.ResourceFactory
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|   304 | getObjectInstance in javax.naming.spi.NamingManager
|   843 | lookup . in org.apache.naming.NamingContext
|   154 | lookup   in     ''
|   831 | lookup . in     ''
|   154 | lookup   in     ''
|   831 | lookup . in     ''
|   154 | lookup   in     ''
|   831 | lookup . in     ''
|   168 | lookup   in     ''
|   158 | lookup . in org.apache.naming.SelectorContext
|   392 | lookup   in javax.naming.InitialContext
|   303 | innerRun in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync
|   138 | run      in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   886 | runTask  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
|   908 | run      in     ''
^   662 | run . .  in java.lang.Thread
| Error 2014-02-06 11:25:59,184 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR core.StandardContext  - Error listenerStart
| Error 2014-02-06 11:25:59,184 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR core.StandardContext  - Context [/osrpms] startup failed due to previous errors
```

Comment: I have the same issue.  Just created a most basic project with one domain class and a one line scafolded controller, and get same error.  New install of 2.4.4 and oracle java 1.7, and latest intelij 13.1 ide

Answer (score 0):

this seems some how your data source setting for grails is not able to access that JNDI data source...i don't think you missed syntax or something but i guess you need to check the server is accessible using the URL and it is app and running ....

`@server` where is the definition ? supposed to be an IP address...

For any help you can check:

Check this [1] [JNDI datasource to oracle with grails 1.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4214404/jndi-datasource-to-oracle-with-grails-1-3)

and Grails Documentation [2] http://grails.org/doc/2.0.0.M2/guide/conf.html

Comment: Server and instance not the real values. But the real value if use for server is the domain name for the Oracle DB server and it resolves to an ip address. The server is up since if I use the url in the datasource instead of the JNDI all works as expected. Thanks for the documentation links.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was Config.groovy

java.sql.DataSource should have been javax.sql.DataSource